# Calling method in object gives SIGBART

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Simple question, but this gives me an error and I can't seem to resolve it.

In my object (UIViewController) I have declared a method in the `.h`

```
-(void)setCurrentLoc:(CLLocation *)loc;
```

and in the `.m`

```
-(void)setCurrentLoc:(CLLocation *)loc
{
    currentLocation = loc;
}
```

All good. But this is how I initiate this object (which works fine) but when I call `setCurrentLoc:` it gives SIGBART

`.h`

```
IBOutlet VectorViewController *vectorView;
```

`.m`

```
vectorView = [[VectorViewController alloc] init];
...
//In another method I call:
[vectorView setCurrentLoc:location]; // Error/SIGBART line
```

Is there something I missed? Maybe not making it global or something?

Error:

> -[UIView setCurrentLoc:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x841cab0

Comment: have you declared and synthetized the currentLocation? maybe you should use a self.currentLocation = loc;

Comment: Yes I did, but it's not that, that gives the error... it's calling the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -[UIView setCurrentLoc:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x841cab0

This means that you are sending the message to a pointer that is no longer pointing at your `VectorViewController`, but is now pointing at a `UIView`. This usually happens when the object has been autoreleased or released and the memory re-used.

Check carefully what happens between when you create vectorView and when you call it again in your other method. You seem to be setting and accessing the instance variable directly - you should probably be accessing it via properties (hard to be specific without knowing if you are using ARC or not) and making sure those properties are declared appropriately.

Comment: This happened because it was mixed with a locationUpdate which occurred before the vectorView was initialized, so I put it inside the locationUpdate (with an if to check if it already exists) - works fine now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've written, you don't need to provide a setCurrentLoc method, use a property instead and synthesize instead.

in your VectorViewController class, use:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CLLocation * currentLocation;
```

in your @implementation, add:

```
@synthesize currentLocation;
```

and in your dealloc method, add:

```
self.currentLocation = nil;
```

Leave your existing setCurrentLocation call as is.

Comment: I know this. But it's not the case... It is because I somehow call it before `vectorView` exists.